# How to Apply Right Hand Rule to Circular Magnetic Fields?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current

Considering this image of the interaction of two current carrying wires

[image]

So the field from $I_1$ induces a magnetic force on $I_2$ and vice versa. How does one prove that the forces do indeed point in the illustrated direction for each example using the right hand rule?

[image]

There are plenty of diagrams such as this one showing how the rule works but they all assume that the magnetic field is point in the same direction. But in the case of the wires the magnetic field direction is always changing and therefore the force direction must also always be changing. So how do we know that the forces point in the direction they do for the interactions between current carrying wires?

Comment: For current flowing in a wire, there is a better right hand rule that describes the situation.  Point your right thumb in the direction of the current (defined as the direction that positive charge carriers would flow).  Now, curl your fingers.  The magnetic field lines curl around the wire in the direction that your fingers are curled (i.e., they move from the base of your fingers towards your finger tips).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just think of the current as a bunch of charges moving upwards/downwards, and the magnetic field generated by each wire remains the same no matter what your y-coordinate is (assuming the wires extend sufficiently long in the y-direction).

[image: diagram of wires and magnetic fields]

Now, you just have a simple problem of charges moving in a magnetic field. If we look at the first wire in case one, there are positive charges moving upwards, and the magnetic field for every point on wire 1 is pointing out of the page (the magnetic field generated by wire 2 doesn't change as you move laterally; it doesn't change as you move up and down). By the right hand rule, the force would be to the right.

Answer (score 0):

consider $\vec B$ due to one wire at position of second wire. You don't need to worry about $\vec B$ at other positions. eg. first case: consider magnetic field at right wire due to first, which is into the plane of screen. Velocity is downward as current is upward. then force is towards left (towards left wire)

Comment: Why don’t we need to consider B at different positions? I agree with the position you chose that the force acting on the right wire would point to the left. But couldn’t you have easily chosen a different B position where it wasn’t point into the screen? And this would affect the direction of the force acting on the right wire?

Comment: For example what position .....? At every point on second wire, the magnetic field is inwards

Comment: Well on the left scenario isn’t the magnetic field $B_2$ pointing into the screen at the right most point on it’s circular path since the direction of the magnetic field at a point is a tangent line to the curved magnetic field line?

Answer (score 0):

Note that two wires carrying current in the same direction will attract each other, and they will repel if the currents are opposite in direction. This is shown on the first figure; in this case, $\vec F_1$ is attracted to $\vec F_2$. Conventionally, when visualising the right hand rule, any changes made to a variable (eg. direction of current, magnetic field or force) will result in changes to the other two. Therefore, given that only the direction of magnetic field is changing, the force will also be affected. In real life, as mentioned, the magnetic field direction is always changing due to the motion of the wire, resulting in changes to the direction of force due to it being dependent. The answer is we can't directly 'predict' the direction of the force based only on the magnetic field.